# How to handle click event being called multiple times with jquery animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a click event that has a Jquery animation in it.
How can i guarantee that the animation has finished when multiple click events are being fired.

```
$(this._ScrollBarTrack).click(function(e) {
         if(e.target === this && _self._horizontalClickScrollingFlag === false){
        _self._horizontalClickScrollingFlag = true;
        if(_self._isVertical){

        } else{ //horizontal

            if(e.offsetX > (this.firstChild.offsetWidth + this.firstChild.offsetLeft)){ // Moving Towards Right
                var scrollableAmountToMove = _self._arrayOfCellSizes[_self._scrollBarCurrentStep + 1]; // additional amount to move
                var scrollableCurrentPosition = -($(_self._bodyScrollable).position().left);
                var scrollBarCurrentPosition = $(_self._ScrollBarTrackPiece).position().left;
                var scrollBarAmountToMove  = _self.getScrollBarTrackPiecePositionBasedOnScrollablePosition(scrollableAmountToMove);
                $(".event-scroll-horizontally").animate({left:-(scrollableCurrentPosition+ scrollableAmountToMove)});
                $(_self._ScrollBarTrackPiece).animate({left: (scrollBarCurrentPosition + scrollBarAmountToMove)});
                _self._scrollBarCurrentStep += 1;
            } else{
                var scrollableAmountToMove = _self._arrayOfCellSizes[_self._scrollBarCurrentStep - 1]; // additional amount to move
                var scrollableCurrentPosition = -($(_self._bodyScrollable).position().left);
                var scrollBarCurrentPosition = $(_self._ScrollBarTrackPiece).position().left;
                var scrollBarAmountToMove  = _self.getScrollBarTrackPiecePositionBasedOnScrollablePosition(scrollableAmountToMove);
                $(".event-scroll-horizontally").animate({left:-(scrollableCurrentPosition - scrollableAmountToMove)});
                $(_self._ScrollBarTrackPiece).animate({left: (scrollBarCurrentPosition - scrollBarAmountToMove)});
                _self._scrollBarCurrentStep -= 1;
            }
        }
        _self._horizontalClickScrollingFlag = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Since you did not set a timer for the animation, you can just add a class to the trigger when clicked. In the handler, just say if self does not have class, execute code. Remove the class on animation complete

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a hidden (I'm not sure why it's not in the docs someplace) variable `$.timers` that you can test against.

I made this function a long time ago to handle situations like this. Mind you, this will test to make sure there are NO animations currently being executed.

```
function animationsTest (callback) {
    var testAnimationInterval = setInterval(function () {

        if ($.timers.length === 0) { // any page animations finished
            clearInterval(testAnimationInterval);
            callback(); // callback function
        }
    }, 25);
};
```

Useage: **[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u2p29wub/)**

```
animationsTest(function () { 
    /* your code here will run when no animations are occuring */ 
});
```

If you want to test against one individually you could do a class/data route.

```
$('#thing').addClass('animating').animate({ left: '+=100px' }, function () { 
    // your callback when the animation is finished
    $(this).removeClass('animating');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could declare a global boolean called `isAnimating` and set it to `true` right when you begin the animation. Then add a `done` or `complete` function to the animation that sets it back to `false`. Then set your click event to only begin the animation if `isAnimating` is `false`.